# How can i predict the function with the given point?

Tags: machine-learning

If i have many point (X,Y) with `Y = f(X) = b0 + b1X + b2X^2 + .. + bkX^k.`
How can i compute `b0, b1, ..., bk` and k.

Answer (score 2):

If you have n points, you choose k = n - 1 and you yield a set of n linear equations with n unknowns. This can be solved e.g. by the Gauss algorithm.

If you don't know the number of points in advance, you can also solve it repetitively. You start with the first point (X0,Y0) and yield

f(X0) = b0 = Y0

With the second point you'll have to take care that the part after b0 vanishes for X0. So your polynomial looks like

f(X) = b0 + b1(X - X0)

Now substitute X1 for X and Y1 for f(X) and calculate b1.

The third point goes alike. Your polynomial then looks like

f(X) = b0 + b1(X - X0) + b2(X - X0)(X - X1)

Calculate b2 from that. And so on